# Why does selecting text in a Command Prompt hang the running application?

Tags: console, command-prompt

We have an application that outputs logging info to `stdout`. However, if it is run in a command prompt window, you can use Mark to select text from the console. If you leave the text selected, the application just hangs and doesn't proceed, until you deselect the text (for example by pressing Enter to copy the selection into the clipboard). After that, the application continues normally. So it acts just like a breakpoint.

Can this behaviour of the command prompt be disabled somehow?

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't be possible if the window kept scrolling. But I think it could have been implemented better, by buffering the output. So only the output would be frozen, and the application should continue to run, with anything that is written to output be actually stored in the buffer. After you quit the selection, the buffer would just flush out to the output console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a "feature" of the command prompt.  I've never found a way to disable it.  You can hit ESC to cancel the selection and allow the process to resume.

Comment: Just learned this is a feature of "QuickEdit mode" which you can turn off in the properties of the command prompt.

Comment: Prev comment must be answer to question.