# Why my console application is buffering log and socket messages?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, windows-10, command-prompt, buffering

**Background:**

I have a Python (console) application which includes a socket server. This application receives messages from a 3rd party client (start and stop messages from certain Process A) to control a recording data task (like start and stop recording). You can think of it as receiving messages via sockets to start and stop recording data from the same Process A for about 5 minutes. The 3rd party client sends messages for nearly 2 hours and then stops, and at the end, the Python application will be producing a group of files per session.

This application is running 24/7 (unattended on a Windows 10 Desktop machine) and there is a logging console open as well, but I have noticed that sometimes (Haven't identified a pattern) after running for 4 or 5 days, I access the system remotely, using TeamViewer, and the console window is showing that the last message is of 1-2 days ago. But once I click on the console or press a key in that console, I receive a full batch of messages from the sessions missed during those last days, thus, start and stop messages are received "simultaneously" leading to rubbish data files.

**The code:**

This is the socket server part of the code. I know I'm setting a buffer of 1024, but in normal operation, this buffer should not be full to read the data

```
            with conn:
                #display client information
                logger.info('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

                while self.enable:
                    #now keep talking with the client
                    data = conn.recv(1024)

                    if data:
                        self.data_cb(data)
                    else:                            
                        logger.debug("no data, closing connection." )
                        break
```

**Question:**

What is leading to this buffering behaviour?
Could it be...

- the 3rd party client?
- my Python application?
- Something in Windows network stuff?

Has anyone had experienced something like this?

Any idea is really appreciated as I have no clue why is this happening? Thanks.

---

***Edit - Additional info:***

- The application is running on a real desktop machine (no virtual machine)
- The application has been able to work continuously for almost a month (just stopped for valid external reasons, power outage, version update, etc)
- Last time I accessed through Teamviewer and noticed that the app wasn't receiving messages for a day (the app was running for 4 days at that time), BUT I assumed it was for another reason and planned to go to the site and check (Because something similar happened before). I accessed the next day, and it was the same. But on the third day, I click on the console and tried to review the messages and instantly the whole batch of messages from the previous 2 days appeared on the log.
- The app has been running for 2 weeks and did not access the PC through TeamViewer during the last 4 days, in case that accessing it could prevent the issue to occur.

Comment: Unless you're in non-blocking mode the sleep is pointless, and if you are you should be using `select()` instead of sleeping and polling.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that could be caused by your app.  A python script generally doesn't have any idea when you "click on the console" unless you explicitly code it in, which it doesn't sound like you did.  If it's a real hardware PC, could it have gone into sleep mode? Or if it's some kind of desktop Virtual Machine could it have been suspended due to inactivity?

Comment: @user207421, I'm using that sleep just as a delay time after a client disconnects, in which case `data == None`. When the client is connected but not sending data `conn.recv()` will block, thus, the sleep is not used.

Comment: @MarkA, It is indeed a "real" DELL desktop machine. I already disabled sleep mode. Actually, the system once ran for almost a month continuously, without issues. But 2 or 3 times I have noticed the behaviour I described before.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense whatsoever. If the client disconnects, the socket must be closed and the read loop terminated. Sleeping before, during, or after that is a complete waste of time.

Comment: I'll take that in mind for the next phase of development. Thanks for your advice @user207421.

Comment: You should take it in mind now. This thread wastes an entire minute trying to read beyond end of stream 60 successive times.

Comment: It's done now @user207421. On the other hand, Do you have something to say about the main issue described in the question?

Comment: Socket / Port exhaustion is a possibility - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend/

Comment: Thanks @MattEvans, I will take a look on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The selection feature of `Command Prompt` window prevents somehow the application from printing logging messages and/or reading data from the socket (both are in the same thread).

---

Well, I found the cause of this buffering behaviour but I am not sure if it is a known thing or not (It was not for me, so I will post later a specific question about that selection feature).

When I checked the system today I found that the console messages were frozen at 3 days before, so *I clicked on the console window*, and *hit a key* and all the messages for 3 days were shown at once. Then, I suspected of the selection feature of the console output.

I started the application as usual and followed these steps:

- I selected a part of the content in the application console.
- Using another console, I connected from a dummy client using `ncat` (At this point the expected `client connected` message didn't show up)
- I sent dummy messages (didn't show up either)
- I finished `ncat` connection (CTRL-C)
- Clicked on the application console and hit any key

Voila! All the logging messages (regarding connection and data appeared), and all the messages that I sent using `ncat` were received as one big message.

---

**EDIT**: Didn't need to create a question, it's a known "feature". There are good questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509816/why-does-selecting-text-in-a-command-prompt-hang-the-running-application), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10). The last one shows how to disable this "feature".